# Empty No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, file, webpack, electron

I'm trying to run an electron app and I keep getting the error "no file or directory" but with no name of directory or file afterward. I'm even more confused when I look at the JavaScript mentioned as the line seems ton only contain a Constant definition

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: No such file or directory
    at eval (webpack:///./src-electron/main-process/tools.js?:24:11)
    at Module../src-electron/main-process/tools.js (/[..]/app/.quasar/electron/electron-main.js:1934:1)
    at __webpack_require__ ([..]/app/.quasar/electron/electron-main.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src-electron/main-process/electron-main.js?:13:65)
    at Module../src-electron/main-process/electron-main.js (/home/mro/archimede-firmware/app/.quasar/electron/electron-main.js:1969:1)
    at __webpack_require__ ([..]/app/.quasar/electron/electron-main.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src-electron/main-process/electron-main.dev.js?:13:1)
    at Object../src-electron/main-process/electron-main.dev.js [..]/app/.quasar/electron/electron-main.js:1957:1)
    at __webpack_require__ ([..]/app/.quasar/electron/electron-main.js:21:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./src-electron/main-process/electron-main.dev.js?:1:18)
```

Looking at the tools.js file at line 24:

```
const DEFAULT_PIECE_COUNT = 80;
```

I'm even more confused as there is no require here or above and below (two const declaration). And I can't seem to find any other question where the error "No such file or directory" has no filename.

Comment: My first attempt would be to delete the node_modules folder and run ``npm install`` again. This solved lots of headaches for me ^^

Comment: You can also check your package.json - maybe some of dependencies is at version with breaking changes for webpack.

Comment: Thanks @Tracer69 I did it a few time alerady still no luck.

Comment: @Zydnar I will look I'm sadly not familiar with the project or who built it do you know if there is a way to know wichi dependecy cause that ?